# How do I measure time taken by a method from logs using Hadoop?

Tags: performance, hadoop, logging, solr

I would like to measure the average time taken for a method call from the logs. There are multiple requests going out to the method at all times and I have the time-stamps of the begin and end of the method call logged. I also have the the thread id so I can track each call. What would be the easiest way to get this using Hadoop? I am using Flume to capture the data. Can use PIG scripting, Solr Cloud, Spark or something else.